# How to get back the real source code of a web page after filling out a Google Recaptcha form in Selenium Python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, xpath-2.0, recaptcha-v3

I am filling out a web form without any issues.

Then I manually fill out the Google Recaptcha.

Then my Python Selenium code suppose to click on the "Submit" button of the web form but it can't. It doesn't find the submit button element.

So I checked it in the Firefox console with $x("") and it found it. I don't understand.
So I tried with form_element.submit(), but it doesn't find either the form element.

So I investigate this issue by printing out the driver.page_source. And this is what it shows:

```
<body>
    <div id="rc-anchor-alert" class="rc-anchor-alert"></div>
    <input type="hidden" id="recaptcha-token"
        value="03AIIukzgVuRMbzNcEe7xajoUUniwCXu_qzI....g6NbIvy47T6NiHF\x22,0,null,null,null,0,[21,41],[4520927,804],0,null,0,0],\x22https://fannyquemener.cmonbook.com:443\x22,[\x22ctask\x22,[[\x22hctask\x22,\x22f5e73494\x22,\x220eb77e17964ac3a3d5c2dfd1e7b5ca7c1e31396c2fd42d8edc9fbf17fc01973d\x22,0,100],[\x22hctask\x22,\x2244d21223\x22,\x22cc551de6e6f9fa666d8e889575e34bd1f89f9e9d483e85b0608c87b89f9943c1\x22,0,100],[\x22hctask\x22,\x22a1e10dd1\x22,\x22cba05b620323e4bea12ea6b0984e9048f77be2675a1a2866cbda315d178577c6\x22,0,100]]],[1,1,1],null,null,null,0,3600,[\x22https://www.google.com/intl/fr/policies/privacy/\x22,\x22https://www.google.com/intl/fr/policies/terms/\x22],\x22vlVSqNo6K4mOcfNk+ejIYMDopeGgcvD85PF1ecMToSk\\u003d\x22,0,0,null,1,1664718680196,0,0,[],null,[]]");
    </script>
    <div id="rc-anchor-container" class="rc-anchor rc-anchor-normal rc-anchor-light">
        <div id="recaptcha-accessible-status" class="rc-anchor-aria-status" aria-hidden="true">Validation terminée</div>
        <div class="rc-anchor-error-msg-container" style="display:none"><span class="rc-anchor-error-msg"
                aria-hidden="true"></span></div>
        <div class="rc-anchor-content">
            <div class="rc-inline-block">
                <div class="rc-anchor-center-container">
                    <div class="rc-anchor-center-item rc-anchor-checkbox-holder"><span
                            class="recaptcha-checkbox goog-inline-block recaptcha-checkbox-unchecked rc-anchor-checkbox recaptcha-checkbox-focused recaptcha-checkbox-checked recaptcha-checkbox-hover recaptcha-checkbox-clearOutline"
                            role="checkbox" aria-checked="true" id="recaptcha-anchor" dir="ltr"
                            aria-labelledby="recaptcha-anchor-label" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0"
                            style="overflow: visible;">
                            <div class="recaptcha-checkbox-border" role="presentation" style="display: none;"></div>
                            <div class="recaptcha-checkbox-borderAnimation" role="presentation" style=""></div>
                            <div class="recaptcha-checkbox-spinner" role="presentation"
                                style="display: none; animation-play-state: running; opacity: 0; transform: scale(0);">
                                <div class="recaptcha-checkbox-spinner-overlay" style="animation-play-state: running;">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark" role="presentation" style=""></div>
                        </span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rc-inline-block">
                <div class="rc-anchor-center-container"><label class="rc-anchor-center-item rc-anchor-checkbox-label"
                        aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" id="recaptcha-anchor-label"><span aria-live="polite"
                            aria-labelledby="recaptcha-accessible-status"></span>Je ne suis pas un robot</label></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rc-anchor-normal-footer">
            <div class="rc-anchor-logo-portrait" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation">
                <div class="rc-anchor-logo-img rc-anchor-logo-img-portrait"></div>
                <div class="rc-anchor-logo-text">reCAPTCHA</div>
            </div>
            <div class="rc-anchor-pt"><a href="https://www.google.com/intl/fr/policies/privacy/"
                    target="_blank">Confidentialité</a><span aria-hidden="true" role="presentation"> - </span><a
                    href="https://www.google.com/intl/fr/policies/terms/" target="_blank">Conditions</a></div>
        </div>
    </div><iframe style="display: none;"></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

My selenium driver doesn't have the elements of the original page anymore but instead, the source code of Google Recaptcha.

Here is my selenium code:

```
def JavascriptClick(p_driver, element):
    p_driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
    p_driver.implicitly_wait(10)

name_model_element = findOneByXPath(p_driver, "//div[contains(@class,'slogan_p')]", 2)
if name_model_element is not None:
    name_model = name_model_element.text
else:
    name_model = ""

# nom
nom_element = findOneByXPath(p_driver, "//input[@name='nom']", 2)
if nom_element is not None:
    ScrollToElement(p_driver, nom_element)
    JavascriptClick(p_driver, nom_element)
    nom_element.clear()
    nom_element.send_keys("Bourgeois")
time.sleep(random.uniform(0.9, 1.3))

# prénom
prenom_element = findOneByXPath(p_driver, "//input[@name='prenom']", 2)
if prenom_element is not None:
    ScrollToElement(p_driver, prenom_element)
    JavascriptClick(p_driver, prenom_element)
    prenom_element.clear()
    prenom_element.send_keys("Alexandra")
time.sleep(random.uniform(0.9, 1.3))

# email
email_element = findOneByXPath(p_driver, "//input[@name='mail']", 2)
if email_element is not None:
    ScrollToElement(p_driver, email_element)
    JavascriptClick(p_driver, email_element)
    email_element.clear()
    email_element.send_keys("contact@social-influencer.net")
time.sleep(random.uniform(0.9, 1.3))
# submit form
print(p_driver.page_source)
form_element = findOneByXPath(p_driver, "//form[@name='form']", 2)
if form_element is not None:
    form_element.submit()
else:

    submit_element = findOneByXPath(p_driver, "//input[@type='submit']", 2)
    if submit_element is not None:
        ScrollToElement(p_driver, submit_element)
        JavascriptClick(p_driver, submit_element)
    else:
        submit_element = findOneByXPath(p_driver, "//input[@name='submit']", 2)
        if submit_element is not None:
            ScrollToElement(p_driver, submit_element)
            JavascriptClick(p_driver, submit_element)
```

And here is the web form:

https://fannyquemener.cmonbook.com/contact.html

Is there a way to get back the elements of this web form?

Comment: Please share your Selenium code

Comment: @Prophet I just did it

Comment: @Prophet I also added the link to the web form. My code is running after I submitted manually the Recaptcha.

Comment: Is that all your code? Where you filling the form? Also why you using `JavascriptClick`, not the regular driver click() ?

Comment: ok. I Just added these details if it can helps you to help me. Thanks.

Comment: @Prophet I am using Javascript click because it is always more effective than the traditional method .click()

Answer (score 0):

All the elements are there on the page, Submit button is also there. After entering the text in 'Message' field, you are clicking on the captcha checkbox or solving the captcha, at that time you have to make the script wait, then the script will click on 'Submit' button.

Try this code, its working, I tried:

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, "nom").send_keys("Test name")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "prenom").send_keys("Test pre-name")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "ville").send_keys("Test ville")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "mail").send_keys("Test_email@gmail.com")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "message").send_keys("Test message")

# you have to solve the captcha, so make the script wait
time.sleep(10)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//input[@name='submit']").click()
```

After entering all the values, I tried printing the page_source also, it is printing the source code for the whole page.